# Pushing a stream of data to S3 and saving as CSV file

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, amazon-s3, stream, large-data

I have a jpa query that gets a response with millions of records. I want this result to be saved as CSV file in S3. As the response is too big, I can't load all the data as a file locally and upload it, I have to stream the data directly to S3. Can I know whether it's possible?